# How to determine if code is unmanaged or CLR?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, .net-core, c++-cli

In a mixed C++/CLI assembly project how can I tell which files/functions will compile natively and which will be managed?

On Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 v16.7.4, .Net SDK v3.1.402:
I created a new "CLR Class Library (.NET Core)" project with the below trivial managed code. The only other change was to disable the precompiled headers (under "*Project Properties → C/C++ → Precompiled headers*").

```
// CLRClassLibraryCore.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;

namespace CLRClassLibraryCore {
    public ref class ManagedClass
    {
    public:
        void Print(System::String^ message);
    };
}

// CLRClassLibraryCore.cpp
#include "CLRClassLibraryCore.h"

namespace CLRClassLibraryCore
{
    void ManagedClass::Print(System::String^ message)
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

As I started creating a native class, I wondered how to ensure it would compile natively rather than to MSIL, and discovered that in Visual Studio .cpp files have a shed-load of extra properties "hidden" in a pop-up properties dialog ("*right-click → Properties*" on file in Solution Explorer).

I was pleased to find a per-file "Common Language RunTime Support" (under "*Configuration Properties → C/C++ → General*"), but can't get it working.
The default value was "NetCore" - which is not one of the 4 options in the drop down...

> *None*
> /clr
> /clr:pure
> /clr:safe

[image: VS CLR options]

I was surprised to see the pure & safe options since [MSVC compiler reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation?view=vs-2019) clearly states the options are "removed in Visual Studio 2017 and later".

So I tested the /clr option and was rewarded during build with:

> ... \3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\mscorlib.dll
> fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
> (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1591)

Digging further I can see that this option is saved in the .vcxproj file `<CompileAsManaged>` tag as "true", "false" or "NetCore".

Whats going on here?
How can I ensure my .Net Core C++/CLI native code is indeed compiled natively?

Background: I've re-engineered a C# .Net Framework assembly to WPF .Net Core and now want to use it from a native C++ plugin of a native C++ app.

Comment: Gross bugs like that tell you what they are working on in the v16.7.x branch.  It was due, the .netcore hosting problem was solved.  And what you should fear, I'd recommend VS2017 and the v16.4.x branch for stability.  As to the core question, keeping native C++ in its own library project is best.

Comment: Apologies @HansPassant - I don't understand: what was due & what problem was solved? I'll gladly keep new native code in it's own library, but I am still stuck on the core question - when inspecting existing source, how do I tell what will compile native and what MSIL?

Comment: The sage of bringing C++/CLI support to .netcore is a long one and just not relevant to your issue.  The advice is unambiguous, use an older stable version of VS to get ahead and do what you tried to do with VS2019.

Comment: Unfortunately not permitted to downgrade VS2019 Community to 16.4 branch it seems. Will try VS2017 thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Write your additional files without inclusion of any non-standard libraries, ie. stick to *STL* (*std* namespace).

Comment: Fine advice, but difficult to evaluate in a large project with nested headers - especially for someone coming back to C++ after a looong absence!

Comment: @moon, this new c++-only files should be your new library, in other words, you will include it into main project, but I would suggest to not include any MS/CLR things in library code.